# Use coroutine inside a non MonoBehaviour class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can you pass a Monobehaviour inside an instance of a non Monobehaviour class? I found this [link](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/running-startcoroutine-from-a-non-monobehaviour.233817/) where TonyLi mentions that you can pass a Monobehaviour to start and stop coroutines inside a instance of a class, but he does not show how you can do that. He does this  theEvent.StartEvent(myMonoBehaviour); but he does not show where he gets myMonobehaviour from. I looked around on the internet but I cannot seem to find how.

- Edit

Here is what I am trying to do. I want to run a coroutine inside an instance of a class. I also want to be able to stop the coroutine inside the instance of the class. I want to do it this way so that I don't have any objects in my scene that have large managers and also so that I can reuse the code for any object that I want to pingpong in this way. The code moves a Gameobject in one direction then takes a break and moves it in the other direction and takes a break again etc. But I cannot start the coroutine from outside the class.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent (typeof(Image))]
public class SpecialBar : MonoBehaviour {

    public float rangeX;
    public float breakTime;
    public float step;
    float startProgress = 0.5f;
    PingPongGameObject pingPonger;

    Color[] teamColors = new Color[]{new Color(255,136,0),new Color(0,170,255)};

    void Start()
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < teamColors.Length; ++i)
        {
            teamColors[i] = StaticFunctions.NormalizeColor (teamColors[i]);
        }

        pingPonger = new PingPongGameObject (gameObject.transform.position,
            new Vector3(rangeX,0.0f,0.0f),
            gameObject,
            startProgress,
            breakTime,
            step
            );
    }
}
```

The second class is where my coroutine is in.

```
public class PingPongGameObject
{
    float step;
    Vector3 center;
    Vector3 range;
    GameObject ball;
    float progress;
    float breakTime;
    Vector3 endPos;
    Vector3 oppositePosition;


    public PingPongGameObject(Vector3 _center, Vector3 _range, GameObject _ball, float _startProgress, float _breakTime, float _step)
    {
        center = _center;
        range = _range;
        ball = _ball;
        progress = _startProgress;
        breakTime = _breakTime;
        step = _step;
        endPos = center - range;
        oppositePosition = center + range;
        // This is where I want to start the coroutine
    }

    public IEnumerator PingPong()
    {


        while (progress < 1) {
            progress += Time.deltaTime * step;
            Vector3 newPos = Vector3.Lerp (oppositePosition, endPos, progress);
            ball.transform.position = newPos;
            yield return null;
        }
        Vector3 temp = endPos;
        endPos = oppositePosition;
        oppositePosition = temp;
        progress = 0;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (breakTime);
        yield return null;
    }

    public float Step
    {
        set{step = value;}
    }

    public void StopCoroutine()
    {
        // This is where I want to stop the coroutine
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I will put an explenation in my question just one moment.

Comment: I reworked the question.

Comment: Check the answer I left. You can use the `this` keyword.

Comment: Hi Mike - ignore my earlier comment saying you need a prefab.  Actually, all you are talking about is *using components!!!!*  It's that simple.

Comment: No, OP want's to use `IEnumerator/Coroutine` in a class that does not derive from `MonoBehaviour`.  Yes he can do but but then **cannot** be able to use the `StartCoroutine` and `StopCoroutine` function and is asking for a way to pass reference of `MonoBehaviour` to the other class so he can be able to do that. You can make a script without making it a `MonoBehaviour`. Sometimes, you have to. Ofcourse, he can make it `MonoBehaviour` like you said in your comments and answer but that's not what the question is about. The question is about passing `MonoBehaviour` reference.

Comment: I appreciate that he has asked (literally) "how to call back to a game object from an abstract c# class I have instantiated".  It's true that that is technically possible but it would be *incredibly wrong!* to do that in Unity - ie, to not understand that the absolutely central idea of Unity - the whole basic process of making Unity programs! - is to write behaviors for things like pingpong, and attach them to objects!

Comment: Just BTW the "fancy-ass" way to do pingpongs and the like is to use **tweeng**  http://stackoverflow.com/a/37228628/294884   .... it's the crack cocaine of Unity development.  Since I feel you want to do it "in code" as it were, that's a good approach.

Comment: 1. write a "PingPing" behavior.  

2. attach it to the GameObject

3. when you want to ping pong, ***just turn it on or off***

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> TonyLi mentions that you can pass a Monobehaviour to start and stop
>   coroutines inside a instance of a class, but he does not show how you
>   can do that. He does this

You are can do that with the `this` keyword. The this keyword will get the current instance of `MonoBehaviour`.

In this example there's a tree, which happens to have a component `MonoScript`:

[image]

That particular instance of `MonoScript` can if it wants (since it's a c# program) instantiate a general c# class, `NonMonoScript`:

Class to pass `MonoBehaviour` from:

```
public class MonoScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        NonMonoScript  nonMonoScript = new NonMonoScript();
        //Pass MonoBehaviour to non MonoBehaviour class
        nonMonoScript.monoParser(this);
    }
}
```

Class that receives pass `MonoBehaviour` instance:

```
public class NonMonoScript 
{
    public void monoParser(MonoBehaviour mono)
    {
        //We can now use StartCoroutine from MonoBehaviour in a non MonoBehaviour script
        mono.StartCoroutine(testFunction());

       //And also use StopCoroutine function
        mono.StopCoroutine(testFunction());
    }

    IEnumerator testFunction()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
        Debug.Log("Test!");
    }
}
```

You can also store the `mono` reference from the `monoParser` function in a local variable to be re-used.

Comment: Thanks guys! Programmer this was exactly what I was looking for. Joe Blow I realize that this may not be the smartest way of dealing with the problem I will look in to it and into your explenation. Since this was the awnser I was looking for I will take this for an awnser.

Comment: @MikeOttink You are welcome. I once ran into this problem of not being able to use the `StartCoroutine` and `StopCoroutine` function. This is how I solved it. Sometimes, you do not need to derive your script from `MonoBehaviour`. Other times you do. It depends on your situation but this answer is only to show how to pass the `MonoBehaviour` to another script like you asked. Joe's answer should also work. Happy coding!

Comment: Passing the monobehaviour in is genius since often it will be called from a monobehaviour. Great for static classes that you want to use project-wide!