# 'Component' does not contain a definition for 'enabled' and no extension method 'enabled'

Tags: c#, arrays, list, unity-game-engine

I am trying to disable and disable a `Component` stored in a `List`. When I try to do so, I get the following error:

> 'Component' does not contain a definition for 'enabled' and no
>   extension method 'enabled' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Component' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

I also tried

```
 components[4].SetActive(false);
```

and get a similar error

```
public List<Component> components;
...
components = new List<Component>();
components.Add(player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_HSV1>());
components.Add(player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_HSV2>());
components.Add(player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_HSV3>());
components.Add(player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_HSV4>());
components.Add(player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_Negative>());
components.Add(player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_Lightning>());
components.Add(player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_MetalFX>());
components.Add(player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_Pixel8bitsC64>());
components.Add(player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_GoldFX>());
components.Add(player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_Waterfall>());
components.Add(player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_Hologram>());
components.Add(player.GetComponent<_2dxFX_PlasmaRainbow>());

components[4].enabled = false;
```

How do I disable a `Component` type in a List?

Comment: You have abstracted the components to the `Component` object, which does not have an `enabled` member. What is your intended result here? You can disable the whole player `GameObject` if you are trying to hide the player, rather than hiding all components individually

Comment: I have a switch case that I will be implementing and I want to disable a script based on the switch case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't enable/disable Unity's [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html) type.

You are looking for [`Behaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour.html). `Behaviours` are `Components` that can be enabled or disabled.

If you store a script reference as `Component` and want to enabled or disable it, cast it to `Behaviour` then you can enable or disable it.

Replace

```
components[4].enabled = false;
```

with

```
Behaviour bhvr = (Behaviour)components[4];
bhvr.enabled = false;
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44540747/what-is-the-difference-between-component-behaviour-and-monobehaviour-and-why-t) for difference between the two.

Comment: man saving my a** <3

Comment: I used "            Behaviour theComponentAsBehaviour = (Behaviour)theComponent;
            theComponentAsBehaviour.enabled = true;
" and got the error "InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid."