# The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following method:

```
protected T AttachComponent<T>(){
    T gsComponent = gameObject.GetComponent<T>();
    if(gsComponent == null){
        gsComponent = gameObject.AddComponent<T>();
    }
    return gsComponent;
}
```

On the `AddComponent` line I am getting the following error:

> The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'GameObject.AddComponent()'. 
>       There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'UnityEngine.Component'.

I am not sure what I can do to fix this error, why Can I not do this?

Comment: you would surely do this **with an extension** in c#.  Here's a tutorial for any beginners reading http://stackoverflow.com/a/35629303/294884 Hope it helps!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The issue is that the [AddObject](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html) method returns a [Component](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html). You need to tell the compiler that your T is actually a type of Component.

Attach a generic constraint to your method, to ensure that your `T`s are `Component`s

```
protected void AttachComponent<T>() where T : Component
{
    // Your code.
}
```

Comment: That gives me this: 'GameObject' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Sorry, I misread your question slightly. I've updated the code in the interim to clarify my answer. Note that the constraint is now on `Component`, not `GameObject` (my mistake)

Comment: No problem! Could you please explain what the "where" part is for?

Comment: It's a [generic constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx). Basically, it tells the compiler that `T` will inherit or implement `Component`, and so the compiler can treat it as a `Component`. There are a number of other constraints you can apply - check the link :)