# How to set texture to automatically match with a change in window size by using same texture

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I made a small 2D game by using unity3D(5.0.2f1). I dragged in some textures to use as the background in a scene. It worked well in the Unity Editor, but not when I built and ran it in a different window size. It didn't look as what I had seen in Unity Editor.

What should I do to change the texture size automatically when window size changes? Here is a screenshot of how the image looks in the editor and the build, as well as my build settings:

[image: Screenshots]

Comment: My English is not good .So I maked atlas to descrip problem better!

Comment: Hi.  your camera.  it is orthographic ?

Comment: Yes !2D game I used orthorgaphic camera.Main camera is only camera in my game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe these will help!

```
//file ExtensionsHandy.cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
public static class ExtensionsHandy
{
public static float OrthoScreenWidth(this Camera c)
    {
    return
        c.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1,1,10)).x
        - c.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0,1,10)).x;
    }

public static float OrthoScreenHeight(this Camera c)
    {
    return
        c.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0,1,10)).y
        - c.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0,0,10)).y;
    }

}
```

try like this

```
   void Start()
     {
     float w = Camera.main.OrthoScreenWidth();
     Debug.Log("w is " +w.ToString("f4");
     }
```

## Note. If not familiar with "extensions": [quick tutorial.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35629303/294884)

Here are more very handy extensions for you.

These will actually ***move an object*** to the screen points!

For example,

```
 transform.ScreenRight();
 transform.ScreenTop();
```

the object, is now at the top-right of the screen!!!

And consider this ......

```
void Update()
  {
  transform.ScreenRight();
  }
```

In that example: even if the user changes the orientation of the device, even if the user resizes the screen (Mac or Windows), the object is ALWAYS on the right of the screen!!

```
public static Vector3 WP( this Camera c, float x, float y, float z)
    {
    return c.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(x,y,z));
    }

public static void ScreenLeft(this GameObject moveme)
    {
    Vector3 rr = moveme.transform.position;

    Vector3 leftTop = Camera.main.WP(0f,1f,0f);
    float leftX = leftTop.x;

    rr.x = leftX;

    moveme.transform.position = rr;
    }

public static void ScreenRight(this GameObject moveme)
    {
    Vector3 rr = moveme.transform.position;

    Vector3 rightTop = Camera.main.WP(1f,1f,0f);
    float rightX = rightTop.x;

    rr.x = rightX;

    moveme.transform.position = rr;
    }

public static void ScreenBottom(this GameObject moveme)
    {
    Vector3 rr = moveme.transform.position;

    Vector3 bottomLeft = Camera.main.WP(0f,0f,0f);
    float bottomY = bottomLeft.y;

    rr.y = bottomY;

    moveme.transform.position = rr;
    }

public static void ScreenTop(this GameObject moveme)
    {
    Vector3 rr = moveme.transform.position;

    Vector3 topLeft = Camera.main.WP(0f,1f,0f);
    float topY = topLeft.y;

    rr.y = topY;

    moveme.transform.position = rr;
    }
```

Hope it helps.....

Comment: Why  ExtensionHandy needn't to inherit from MonoBehaviour?

Comment: How to get MainCamera in static class ExtensionHandy?I am a fresh man in unity3D.so...Would you please help me more?Thank you very much.

Comment: yeah! I found that your code extended Camera.main. I had tried.But what does the method of WP means?

Comment: heh no problem.  please write new questions.  "reactive" layout ("size of screen") is very difficult issue ...... extremely difficult

Comment: Stack over flow doesn't allow me to ask question any more!Because I asked a question not long before!I am a fresh man in StackOverFlow..so sorry... English is  very useful for coder .But My English is bad..