# Get position of an object up to 3 decimal places in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I instantiate an object on a mouse click. I need to get transform position x and y upto 3 decimal places. Here is my code.

```
void OnMouseDown()
    {
        ray=Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if(Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit))
        {

            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
            {
                GameObject obj=Instantiate(prefab,new Vector3(hit.point.x,hit.point.y,hit.point.z), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                OrbsList.Add(new Vector3(obj.transform.position.x,obj.transform.position.y,0));
            }

        }
    }
```

Right now if a obj is instantiated at position (4.53325, 3.03369, 0) it is saved as (4.5,3.0,0). I want to save it's position as  (4.53325, 3.03369, 0). Please help thanks.

Comment: It is saved where you want it to be, it is just the display that is simplified.

Comment: @Everts Oh you are right. I just converted x and y to string and they show exact positions not rounded off. Thanks and i feel stupid now

Comment: careful, floats only have a limited precision and the values you use here are precice enough to not show the desired results once you use them in calculations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the record, `Debug.Log` annoyingly prints only one decimal place.

Do this

```
Vector3 pos = obj.transform.position;
Debug.Log("pos x is now " + pos.x.ToString("f3"));
Debug.Log("pos y is now " + pos.y.ToString("f3"));
Debug.Log("pos z is now " + pos.z.ToString("f3"));
```

**BUT NOTE!**

There's good news: Unity sensibly added "ToString" to Vector3. So, you can just do this:

```
Vector3 pos = obj.transform.position;
Debug.Log("pos is now " + pos.ToString("f3"));
```

Fortunately it's that easy.

---

For anyone reading who is a new programmer, this is a great opportunity to learn about **extensions**. [Quick extensions tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35629303/294884).

```
public static class Handy
   {
   public static float Say(this GameObject go)
      {
      Debug.Log(go.name + ", position is ... "
             + go.transform.position.ToString("f3");
      }
```

So now you can do this...

```
 obj.Say();
```

...anywhere in your project.

Comment: is there a way to do it without casting it to string first ?

Comment: @MaciekWoźniak (1) you can simply Debug.Log("hello " + c);  (2) you can also: Debug.Log($"hello {x}");  But if you WANT THE FORMATTING (re-read the first sentence of this answer) you have to do what it says in the answer.  All the best