# Input.mousePosition with 4-5 digits of decimal precision?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, coordinates, mouse-position

I need to obtain display coordinates of the mousePosition by clicking "Fire1" button. The script is very simple, and I get what I need. But I would like the coordinates to be more precise.

```
public class exmp : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public void Update()
     {
         if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
         {
             Debug.Log(Input.mousePosition.x + ", " +Input.mousePosition.y);
         }
     }
 }
```

Currently I'm getting smth like "x, y" or "x.5, y.0", but it is important for the project to get something like "x.abcd, y.efgh". In some examples I've seen that this is quite possible, but I can't figure out how.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Input.mousePosition is in pixel coordinates, it should range from (for example) 0 to 1600, not decimal values?

Comment: @nbura I used to think the same way, but it appears that it's not, can't really explain why. The problem is that Debug.Log rounds the output, and I want to avoid it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get position of an object up to 3 decimal places in unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37162041/get-position-of-an-object-up-to-3-decimal-places-in-unity)

Comment: @dom93 I've seen that question. There is a bit different function there, where the code includes Vector3. I tried to use the solution, but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Input.mousePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html) indeed returns a `Vector3` with `float` values, though it is in pixel-coordinates but also returns inbetween pixel positions.

Anyway actually only the string printing to the console is affected by the lower precision because Unity uses a custom `ToString()` implementation for `Vector3` and `float` which is supposed to be better readable.

If you use those values for any calculation it uses the pure `float` values with an even higher precision of [~6-9 digits](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types).

---

For the printing checkout [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) and [Custom Numeric format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)

You can e.g. use

```
Debug.Log(Input.mousePosition.x.ToString("0.0000") + ", " + Input.mousePosition.y.ToString("0.0000"));
```

or using [`"Fn"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-fixed-point-f-format-specifier)

```
Debug.Log(Input.mousePosition.x.ToString("F4") + ", " + Input.mousePosition.y.ToString("F4"));
```

in order to show a `float` value with a precision of **always* 4 decimals.

You can instead also use `#` for *optional* precision so it is cut off if the precision is not required e.g. for

```
Debug.Log(1.23001f.ToString("0.00##"));
Debug.Log(1.2301f.ToString("0.00##"));
```

the output will be

```
1.23
1.2301
```