# Unity3D, how can I write an extension method for operators?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, operator-overloading, extension-methods

I am trying to extend [Vector3](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) which is a Unity3D feature.  It does not have a less than operator, so I am trying to create one.  However, When I write the extension method for it, my IDE tells me "Identifier expected, 'this' is a keyword".

How can I write an extension method using operators?  This is my attempt, which unexpectedly did not work:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public static class Vector3Extensions
{
    public static bool operator <(this Vector3 vector3, Vector3 other)
    {
        if (vector3.x < other.x)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (vector3.x > other.x)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (vector3.y < other.y)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (vector3.y > other.y)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (vector3.z < other.z)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: here's a quick introduction to Extensions for any new Unity programmers googling to here ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/35629303/294884   Note that in Unity, extensions are the most basic thing - you use them constantly at all times.  Almost all Unity code has extensions on almost every line.  It's the "basic idea" of engineering in Unity, on the code side.

Comment: how does this describe a vector less than another in the first place? assuming less or more would be reasonable terms for vectors. the only thing where less or more make sense is a vectors magnitude and you get that as a float. yes i know that has nothing to do with your actual question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not use extension method to overload on operator. Perhaps you can add `.LessThan`.

Answer (score -2):

It's not extension methods but operator overloads.  See this [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s(v=vs.71).aspx) that states:

> ==, !=, <, >, <=, >=  The comparison operators can be overloaded (but see note below).
>   Note   The comparison operators, if overloaded, must be overloaded in pairs; that is, if == is overloaded, != must also be overloaded. The reverse is also true, and similar for < and >, and for <= and >=.

Complete documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: To do that you would need to put it inside of the Vector3 class, which is a part of Unity and can't be edited.

Comment: Oh yeah my bad.  I didn't realize that.